# ¿Que hacer para que se cambie el boton de login por logout?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy intentando solucionar como hacer para que se cambie el botón de login por el logout.
El boton lo tengo en la navbar. Y quiero que el cliente cuando entre en mi página y inicia sessión, que no le salga el boton de iniciar session otra vez sino que se cambie a cerrar session.

Comment: Con php debes guardar en $_SESSION, por ejemplo, una vez el usuario se ha identificado correctamente, y con un if puedes comprar si ha iniciado la sesión y cambiar el botón por el correspondiente

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, para que sea más sencillo ayudarte. Lee [ask].

Comment: La condicion es simple... SI hay una sesion iniciada, mostrar el logout y ocultar el login, viceversa para lo contrario.

Comment: muchas gracias a todos